# jQuery error - according to Chrome

Tags: jquery, syntax-error, web-deployment

This code is not working, I then checked the code by clicking on `Inspect element`. It then says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Here is the code

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#lyrics_button").click(function(){
        $("#lyrics").slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you add the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before your script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```